# htlatex adding _ after - in URLs

Tags: formatting, texlive, tex4ht, debugging, htlatex

I'm using `htlatex` on Fedora 21, `texlive-tex4ht-svn33024.0-1.1`

I noticed that whenever a URL has a hyphen within it,
in the HTML output it's formatted with an underscore symbol following `-`. For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,titlepage]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\url{http://google-moogle.com}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html >
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)"> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)"> 
<!-- html --> 
<meta name="src" content="test.tex"> 
<meta name="date" content="2015-01-24 23:06:00"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 7--><p class="noindent" ><a 
href="http://google-moogle.com" class="url" ><span 
class="cmtt-10">http://google-_moogle.com</span></a>
</body></html>
```

Note `_` after `-`.

I didn't see this previously on Fedora 20.

I found a work-around: redefining `-` within URL's to add an `mbox` around it seems to help:

```
\makeatletter \g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\do\-{\mbox{-}}}
```

but I'd like to better understand what's going on here.

Comment: I get `<span class="cmtt-10">http://google-moogle.com</span>` with no underscore (but I'm not on Fedora).